# Android StrictMode Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called

Tags: android

I'm seeing a StrictMode failure, and I can't see what's wrong with what I'm doing. The failure is:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:528)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:836)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
    E/StrictMode(26875):    at com.mycompany.MyClass.sendJson(MyClass.java:267)
```

I configure StrictMode:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
              .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().detectLeakedClosableObjects().penaltyLog()
                    .penaltyDeath().build());
}
```

The code looks something like the following:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;
InputStream in = null;

try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://our.server/some/path").openConnection();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection
                .setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

        String content = "{\"some\":\"json data\"}";
        byte bytes[] = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
        outputStream.write(bytes);
        outputStream.flush();

        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); // This is line 267 in the stack trace

        if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == responseCode
                || HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED == responseCode) {

            // do something with a successful response
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // report the exception
} finally {
    if (null != connection) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    if (null != outputStream) {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (null != in) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I found somebody complaining of seeing the same StrictMode failure when using Google AdMob SDK (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/yVss4ufdPp4) but I've not been able to find any solution so far.

Comment: Tried to (on gziped HTTP response), but can't reproduce the Exception. Are you setting an explicit [StrictMode policy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)? What's your Android SDK version?

Comment: I've edited the question to show how I'm configuring StrictMode

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? To me it looks like a bug in Android's GZIPInputStream, since it creates an Inflater, registers a close guard for "end", but then never actually calls end.

Comment: I've yet to get around to trying bwt's solution, mainly because the server we're talking to was updated, and I'm always getting HTTP_OKs back now, so the leaky code path isn't being triggered. But it does seem like a bug to me, I'd agree.

Answer (score 6):

What happens if you get the response stream, read it completely and close it (even if the response code is not OK).
I think this will invoke `HttpEngine.release()`, and thus avoid the exception when the `GzipInputStream` is later finalized (as the exception is prepared in the constructor but throwed in `finalize()`)

Comment: This looked promising, but it did not work for me, in a similar piece to Jonathan. Tested with 4.1.2 on a Nexus S.

Comment: Interestingly a [similar suggestion and fix](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/24/files#diff-a717786a862ad3d4b9846a5168428cc9R96) in [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

Answer (score 4):

I think `connection.getResponseCode()` opens an input stream. So you will need to retrieve the input stream and close it.

Comment: This resolved my similar StrictMode problem! Thank you!! Code snippet: connection.getInputStream().close()

Comment: @PaniniLuncher thanks it works for me.I m getting this similar because of `connection.getContentLength()`. this.